# testing whether property exists on an object and is equal to a certain value

Tags: javascript

let's say that we have an javascript object like below:

```
let obj = {name: 'firstName'};
```

which is a better way to test whether a property exists on an object and is equal to something:

1)

```
if (obj.address === 'someAddress')
```

or

2)

```
if (!!obj.address && obj.address === 'someAddress')
```

Can someone explain which is better/safer and why?

Comment: What sense does it make to use 2)? If the property has the value you want, then it logically follows that the property exists. If it doesn't have the value you want, then it makes no difference whether it exists or not, considering the outcome is the same.

Comment: 2nd one is better because first you check whether on object contain address or not and then you get and compare value.

Comment: @treadkhuram so, what is the difference if the property doesn't exist?

Comment: @V If property doesn't exist then 2nd && statement will not execute.

Comment: @treadkhuram so what is *the difference*? The whole `if` won't execute in either case - whether you check for the property or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked "safer" and "better". "Better" is subjective as long as you don't define what qualities you're looking for, so I'll ignore that part.

Accessing a property that doesn't exist is valid in JavaScript, and simply returns `undefined`. So the second way is equivalent to:

```
const address = obj.address
if (!!address && address === 'someAddress') {
    ...
}
```

Now you can see that that's plain silly, because the second condition implies the first. In other words, there is no way that `address === 'someAddress'` can be `true` and `!!address` can be `false`, so there is no need to do the first check at all.

**So the second approach is not safer than the first.** Both have the same observable effect.

---

Nitpicker's corner: if you were checking for some falsy value like `0` or `""` instead of the truthy string `'someAddress'`, then the second approach would not even work, because both conditions can never be true at the same time.

Also, if `address` is a property with an evil getter that may return a different value each time it's called, all bets are off. The first version could actually be safer because it only gets the value once, but presumably the value would be used inside the `if` block so the code is still broken.

Answer (score 1):

1 is shorter :D and it works :D

Answer (score -1):

Better is:

```js
if (obj?.address === 'someAddress')
```

it checks both conditions

Comment: This checks if `obj` is nullish or not, it's not a check if `address` is falsy.

Comment: @VLAZ nullish opperator is **??**

Comment: `?.` is optional chaining which will only access the property if the value you used it on is not nullish. `obj?.address === 'someAddress'` is equivalent to `obj ?? obj.address  === 'someAddress'` and not to `!!obj.address && obj.address === 'someAddress'`

Comment: If you have nested object like **obj.some.some2.some3.some4** optional chaining is better (my subjective opinion)

Comment: But it's *a semantically different operation* to the two things OP mentioned.